# To set item on the center of screen using Linearlayout

Tags: android-linearlayout, android

I  use Linearlayout as my root layout view.And now I want to let  my imageview which sets on the center of my screen.But as there are many other items in the ,so I can hardly use "android:gravity="center"" to cpmplete my function.

I know one way to solve the problem is to use relativeLayout instead of linearlayout,but I want to find a way to also use linearlayout.
And the layout.xml like the code below:

```
<LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout/>
<RelativeLayout/>
<ImageView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set android:layout_gravity="center" for your ImageView?

Comment: Can you give more info such as your LinearLayout orientation? Vertical or horizontal? For your image you want it to be center horizontal or vertical? You mention there are other view inside the linear layout as well?

Comment: I edit the question,and the layout is like above.I want to set the image to be both center horizontal and vertical of the whole linnearlayout,and the linearlayout is vertical now.

Comment: if your linear layout has vertical orientation, then all the views inside will be rendered by the order you define in the xml from top to bottom. It's not possible to set a view to be center_vertical in this case. For your purpose, I think RelativeLayout with android:layout_centerInParent="true" should work better.

Comment: yeah,thank you.Because of there are many layout seems like this,so I want to find a simeple way to resolve them.If there is no method,I'll rewrite the relativeLayout.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think linearlayout often use as one by one,and I suggest you to use RelativeLayout instead